# Apache Solr or Lucene proximity search on multiple fields

Tags: solr, lucene, nosql

Is it possible in solr/lucene to search on different multivalued fields?
Imagine to have an XML fragment like this:

```
<normative>
 <ref><aut>State</aut><num>70</num>><year>2007</year><article>13</article></ref>
 <ref><aut>TreasuryMinistry</aut><num>350</num><year>2011</year><article>21</article></ref>
</normative>
```

Is it possible to retrieve documents containing for instance:
    num:70 AND year:2007 
inside the same ref ?
i.e. this document should not be found for a query like
    num:70 AND year:2011.

I could create catenated fields like

```
   <ref cat='state-0070-2007-0013'/>
   <ref cat='TreasuryMinistry-0350-2011-0021'/>
```

but the user must be able to find by every combination of fields, i.e.
        num and year,
        year and article,
        num and article,
        aut and num and year,
on the same ref!
I am not experienced with solr/lucene, so I fear that a wild card search like

```
cat:'*-0070-2007-*'
```

could not be not performant over our normative document corpus.

Is there a way to make a search based on relative position?
Something like using copyField to a multivalue field with different positionincrementGaps?

Answer (score 0):

Not directly answering your proximity question, but can you treat each  as a document? If so, then a search like 'num:70 AND year:2007' should work fine, assuming you create the 'num' and 'year' fields.

Comment: The need is to find all judgements, ordinances and jurisprudence material with references to normative given by the user. In a relation     model it is a join operation, that can be done by inserting foreign keys into the documents or in a third table. The fact is that there are preexisting huge normative records with the absence of a truly unique key field.